# Flask migration fails

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm making migrations in Flask using unsurprisingly `Flask-Migrate`.
once I execute `python manage.py db init` it creates directory `migrations` with initial migrations file. Then
I execute `python manage.py db migrate` and I get this:

```
...
...
target_metadata = current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.metadata
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'metadata'
```

I understand from this output that 'migrate' is `None` hence I'm getting an attribute error.

models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from project import db, bcrypt


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True, nullable=False)
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now(), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode()

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'username': self.username,
            'email': self.email,
            'active': self.active,
        }
```

The question is why nothing is being passed to it ? I'm following a tutorial and I'm not supposed to have this error.

I've got this from similar topic:

> NoneType means that instead of an instance of whatever Class or Object
>   you think you're working with, you've actually got None. That usually
>   means that an assignment or function call up above failed or returned
>   an unexpected result.

this is what I've found in env.py file in the migrations directory:

```
from flask import current_app
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url',
                       current_app.config.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'))
target_metadata = current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.metadata
```

`current_app` is being imported from Flask but doesn't contain the extension `migrate` from which I need to use the metadata.

There's no reason for it to be throwing `None` though because the extension is correctly initilised in `__init__.py` file:

```
...
...
from flask_migrate import Migrate

db = SQLAlchemy()
toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension()
cors = CORS()
migrate = Migrate()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()

def create_app(script_info=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app_settings = os.getenv('APP_SETTINGS')
    app.config.from_object(app_settings)
    app.config.from_object('project.config.DevelopmentConfig')
    toolbar.init_app(app)
    cors.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app)     #  <--
    bcrypt.init_app(app)

    from project.api.users import users_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(users_blueprint)

    @app.shell_context_processor
    def ctx():
        return {'app': app, 'db': db}

    return app
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a missing argument in the initialization of the `migrate` extension. Migrate takes in the `app` instance **and** the instance of `db`.

```
def create_app(script_info=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app_settings = os.getenv('APP_SETTINGS')
    app.config.from_object(app_settings)
    app.config.from_object('project.config.DevelopmentConfig')
    toolbar.init_app(app)
    cors.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)     #  <--
    bcrypt.init_app(app)

    from project.api.users import users_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(users_blueprint)

    @app.shell_context_processor
    def ctx():
        return {'app': app, 'db': db}

    return app
```

Comment: Thank you! I made the same mistake and forgot to pass db to migrate.init_app ...